# Block does not display in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Take a look at this with IE or Chrome and notice the yellow block:
http://vansschoenenonline.com/portfolio/vans-era-goldcoast-ginger-bread/

Now open the same page in firefox and magic happens... the block disappeared.

Does anyone know what causes this?
Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the `position:relative` from `.single-portfolio .entry-content` class and add these properties in your div style `left: 0;
top: 314px;` which keeps "Goedkoopste shop:" text
it may help you

Comment: almost right... it is vissible now, but not in the right place.
EDIT: with a little extra tweak this did the trick. will mark as correct answer. thanks a lot!

Comment: use firebug for proper layout. you can set the position where you want

Answer (score 5):

Your HTML is invalid:

```
<h5><h2>Goedkoopste shop:</h2></h5>
```

Headings cannot be nested, browsers do what they please with errors and each one may be different.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fvansschoenenonline.com%2Fportfolio%2Fvans-era-goldcoast-ginger-bread%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

> Validation Output: 2 Errors
>
> **Line 154, Column 84: Heading cannot be a child of another heading.**
>   `…10px 0 -5px 3px;; margin-bottom:-5px;">Goedkoopste
>   shop:</h2></h5><span style=…`
>
> **Line 154, Column 111: Stray end tag
>   h5**. `…ttom:-5px;">Goedkoopste shop:</h2></h5><span
>   style="margin-left:3px;">Fresh Co…`

Comment: Allthough that is true (changed it) it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in style.css :

```
.single-portfolio .entry-content .entry-meta { 
    left: 0; 
    width: 220px;
}

.gecko.single-portfolio .entry-content .entry-meta { left: -240px; }
```

There is ambiguity on which `left:xxx` applying on your `div.entry-meta`. Firefox apply the last one, contrary to Chrome and IE (it's possible that they consider that the first `.gecko.single-portfolio` renders the whole rule invalid).

If you use Firefox developer tools, you'll see that the one saying `left: -240px;` is applied. If you uncheck it, your block is visible as in other browsers.

If you remove this line :

```
.gecko.single-portfolio .entry-content .entry-meta { left: -240px; }
```

(or make it so that it's not applied on this block) it will be OK

Comment: It's not ambiguity; his scripts are UA-sniffing and only setting the `.gecko` bit in Firefox....